# Reverse Tethering via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, tethering

Doing some googling I have found the possibility to create a PAN network with a Windows Machine to give network access to an Android Bluetooth device. At robotics where I am at we are NOT ALLOWED TO CREATE OUR OWN WIRELESS CONNECTIONS [WiFi]! (So no APs, AdHoc, Hidden SSID, NFC, etc.!)

With that said I would not like to step into haveing to deal with P2P considering we need live updates and Internet Access to communicate with an API.

Question: How can I setup the reverse Tether in windows? I have followed some tutorials and other How-to guides and other posts for other issues but so far none have worked.

Any Ideas will be helpful to further develop the ideas.

Comment: So, you want to share your PC's connection via bluetooth? Or you want to connect to PC and force grab connection?

Comment: Share the PC's Network connection via Bluetooth. I have tried just connection it but the PAN options are not available. Thanks for your reply.